# About $C(K)$-spaces containing no copy of $l_{1}$

Tags: banach-spaces

Let $K$ be a compact Hausdorff space. I wonder whether there are characterizations of $K$ such that $C(K)$ contains no copy of $l_{1}$. There are some compact Hausdorff spaces $K$ such that $C(K)$ contains no copy of $l_{1}$, for example, if $K$ is a countable compact metric space and has finite Cantor-Bendixson index. Are there more compact Hausdorff spaces $K$ such that $C(K)$ contains no copy of $l_{1}$?

Thank you!

Comment: no *subspace* isomorphic/isometric to $\ell^1$?

Comment: no subspace isomorphic to $l_{1}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is such characterisation. $C(K)$ contains no isomorphic copy of $\ell_1$ if and only if $K$ is scattered. Indeed, if $K$ is scattered then $C(K)^*$ is isometric to $\ell_1(K)$, so $C(K)$ cannot contain $\ell_1$, as then $C(K)^*$ would have contained a copy of $L_1$. Conversely, if $K$ is not scattered, then you may find a copy of $C[0,1]$ in $C(K)$.

Comment: Could you tell me the reference about the above result  you mentioned.

Comment: @DongyangChen, I think you will find this in H. Lotz, N. T. Peck and H. Porta, Semi-embeddings of Banach spaces, *Proc. Edinburgh Math. Soc.* (2) **22** (1979), no. 3, 233-240.

Comment: The result is due to Pelczynski and Semadeni: $$ $$ Pełczyński, A.; Semadeni, Z.
Spaces of continuous functions. III. Spaces C(Ω) for Ω without perfect subsets. 
Studia Math. 18 1959 211–222.